# Calculation of calories from HKHealthStore energy burned query

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am working on collecting active energy burned samples from HKHealthStore (Apple Watch device).
Does anybody know how exactly is the active energy burned calculated here? I guess it's from type of activity, duration and heart beat. Are also gyroscope, accelometer measurement used in calculations? Or what exactly is used?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The exact approach to computing energy burn on Apple Watch is not documented publicly by Apple, so any answer to this question would be speculation.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Fair enough. I didn't want someone else to leave a speculative answer that got accepted, though.